# Safari won't -webkit-transform: scale()

Tags: css, safari, webkit, scale

Help me. I'm desperate

I'm close to finishing up my webpage, and I made a temporary domain when my pal says it's messed up on Safari. I check it out and I really can't solve it.

The issue is I downscale all the images and logos to make them fit, and Safari doesn't want me to. An example;

```
.midlogo {
overflow:hidden;
z-index: 1;
background-image: url(images/whitelogo.png);
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
-ms-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
-moz-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
-o-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
top: -840px;
left: -650px;
height: 2560px;
width: 2560px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I've tried almost everything, and I'm out of ideas. -webkit- works in Chrome, but refuses in Safari.

Help me

Please

jsfiddle; [https://jsfiddle.net/s8mm8Lm2/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/s8mm8Lm2/)

Comment: can we get a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: jsfiddle created, question updated!

Comment: try this instead for the jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5u3zb768/). I've added a placeholder image and closed the CSS. I'm looking at the problem it might have something to do with background images in jpg format. Have you tried another format?

Comment: remember to put quotes inside the URL: `background-image="url ('importantToPutQuotesAroundThis.png')"` I have a working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5u3zb768/1/). You can see there is an image displayed in Safari. So use **png picture format** to play it safe

Comment: Still didn't fix it... Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Your jsfiddle example is missing the ending squiggly bracket `}` for your CSS rule. And the image your using is a local image with a relative path. Throwing an error in jsfiddle browser console for image not found `images/whitelogo.png`

Comment: It works on my environment. I test it on Safari 9.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I got this fixed, and I have no idea how. -webkit- will always remain a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem when I noticed that some of my span elements were getting `scale(.75)` and others were not.

The only difference between the two elements was that elements that were successfully scaling were the ones that had  `display:block`.

Scaling was fixed when I added `display:block` to all inline elements that I wanted to scale.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxexjs72/)'s a fiddle that demonstrates the difference in how inline elements are treated by the scale transform:
https://jsfiddle.net/xxexjs72/